# Understanding spatial and temporal locality

Tags: c, cache-locality

I was studying for my architecture final and came across the following lines of code:

```
for(i = 0; i <= N ;i++){
   a[i] = b[i] + c[i]; 
}
```

The question is: "How does this code snippet demonstrate examples of temporal and spatial locality? Be sure to consider
memory references for both data and instructions."

In terms of spatial locality I believe the code demonstrates it by accessing contiguous memory locations (a[0] then a[i] etc). However, my confusion comes with temporal locality. I'm not sure how this snippet of code references the same location within a small period of time? Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code doesn't *reference the same location within a small period of time*, because it only "references" each location once, unless `a == b || a == c || b == c`.

Comment: The variable `i` is accessed a lot in a small amount of time.

Comment: @JGroven the question is about *`a[0]` then `a[i]` etc.* although your point does consider *Be sure to consider memory references for both data and instructions*

Comment: @WeatherVane that's just OP's explanation of spatial locality, not the question.  The question is about spatial and temporal locality.

Comment: I edited previous comment as you typed.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for the explanation. So basically you are saying this code doesn't demonstrate temporal locality at all? If so, a trick question!

Comment: Well, @JGroven pointed out the continuous use of the control variable `i` although that might not be implemented in a memory location, but in a processor register.

Comment: I think *instructions* is the key word here ... you have several instructions inside that for loop ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure how this snippet of code references the same location within a small period of time?

As has been commented, the variable `i` is accessed quite frequently, take the following line of code in your example:

```
a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
```

In this example, `a`, `b` and `c` all presumably refer to array types pointing to different memory locations (even if contiguous, still different); however, the variable `i` is *read* each time it is referenced to then determine the location of the array to reference.

Think of it this way:

```
get i from memory and store value in register x.
get value of b + [value in register x] from memory, store in register b.
get i from memory and store value in register y
get value of c + [value in register y] from memory, store in register c.
get i from memory and store value in register z
add value of [register b] to value in [register c] and store in memory location a + [value in register z]
```

An optimizing compiler would likely see this temporal locality and instead do something similar to the following:

```
get i from memory and store value in register i.
get value of b + [value in register i] from memory, store in register b.
get value of c + [value in register i] from memory, store in register c.
add value of [register b] to value in [register c] and store in memory location a + [value in register i]
```

It is in this way that `i` has a temporal proximity between adjacent references.

I hope that can help.

Comment: This is sub-question but if there is no compiler optimization here, how would you optimize OP code to improve temporal locality?

Comment: @GRC it depends on the specifics of the code in this case (especially since this is just an academic question), but the most likely optimization I would do is something similar to the following: `while (N-- >= 0) { *a++ = *b++ + *c++; }` .. but that makes certain assumptions of the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how this snippet of code references the same location
>   within a small period of time.

In addition to [txtechhelp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164834/8767209), the *instructions* that make up that for loop are also stored in memory.  These instructions are "fetched" from memory/cache each time they are executed. Since each of these instructions is executed N+1 times in a very short time frame, this demonstrates temporal locality.